# Implies arrow in the northeast direction

Tags: arrows, mathjax

How to create an arrow with a similar shape as the `\implies` arrow, but not in the right direction, say in the northeast direction. Thanks.

Edit: I am using mathjax.

Comment: The `MnSymbol` package features a `\Nearrow` command.  (Note the capitalization, also of the name of the package!)

Comment: Do you know how to realize it in mathjax?

Comment: Sorry, I have never ever used mathjax in all my life!

Comment: Since mathjax is not using latex, this question (the mathjax part) does probably not belong here. Mathjax is a Javascript library that knows some latex syntax, plus a font that contains base symbols. As packages have no meaning in mathjax, you cannot use anything outside of the list provided by the mathjax people. If you are lucky, this symbol might be in the Stix font, and perhaps mathjax can access it that way, but again this is not a latex related question anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The `txfonts` or `pxfonts` packages have a command `\Nearrow` and similar for other directions:

[image]

And these are just the first results in the very detailed [symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) document.

Comment: Do you know how to realize it in mathjax?

Comment: In the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-extensions), I couldn't find one of the standard LaTex packages that provide this symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to switch to Times font:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{MnSymbol}



\begin{document}

You don't need to switch to Times: $abc$, $\alpha\beta\gamma$, and 
$\Nearrow$,~$\Searrow$,~$\Swarrow$,~$\Nwarrow$.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the code]